# Combining a horizontal bar graph and stock chart (with navigator) HighCharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to create a graph with two sections; the top section is a horizontal bar graph showing categories at the left. The second, lower, graph will be a spline graph showing values at right, and both graphs will use the x-axis of time.

I'm trying to format the HighStock chart to look like this:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/revive/n4H8U/show/light/

And here is my WIP: http://jsfiddle.net/revive/g4KLk/

The top sections category bars will act as 'indicators' to show whether that category is ON or OFF during that time period.

```
The bottom section shows various speed measurements, over the same time frame.
```

And, the reason I'm trying to make this work with the HighStocks chart, is that I need that zoom/pan navigator at the bottom :D

Any feedback is greatly appreciated, as I've gone as far as I can in the API with my current understanding of it.. still learning it!

Thanks!

## **EDIT**

Maybe it's best I define the end result that I am trying to accomplish, since there very well might be a better way to go about it.

Obviously the two graph data sets I have are based on time - they both have data points over a period of time.

What I need is for a user to be able to view the graphs, based on the timeline. Be able to 'zoom' in (hence the desire to use the Navigator in HighStocks) and then pick a data point as a 'Start Time' and another as an 'End Time' so we can return other data based on that newly selected time frame.

### Here's a live example:

> Let's say you have an audio or video recorded over a 2 hour period, with additional data to show when/how long your camera light, motion detector, flash, etc. were active for. Using this graph you're able to scroll through the data (with the top graph showing the bars representing the state of the camera light, motion detector, etc. related to time and the bottom graph shows the sound level in DB - both graphs share the same timeline - xAxis).
>
> This way, you could use the Navigator to zoom into a specific time frame within that 2 hour window.. and then identify when a specific event occurred (eg. the motion detector was active from 1:33:00 to 1:48:29) and you want to 'extract' those two time markers for use elsewhere..

As with most complex UI patterns.. It's fairly difficult to describe, but in practice is pretty straight forward to use :D

Comment: Can you send the full fiddle so we can see your code? Have you tried using 'bar' for your top chart in your WIP graph? What happens if you do that?

Comment: You have two completely different xAxis, first is number from 0 to 32, but second is datetime (time in miliseconds) which hase values i.e 12392992000, so would like to map it? which time is i.e number 4?

Comment: Hi @SebastianBochan, thanks for the quick response! The different Axis' are due to my lack of understand of the HighCharts API - still reading through it. 
The bottom Axis for both charts should be time (usually within a short span, though up to several hours.).
Since I need to use a horizontal bar chart for the top, I realize that the Axis are flipped - xAxis is the left, yAxis is the bottom. 
So, that would make it so the top, vertical bar chart would need: 
xAxis: status value, yAxis: time    
and then the chart would be:
xAxis: time
yAxis: speed value

Is that correct?

Comment: Mainly, I've not been able to sort out HOW to allow the use of a vertical bar chart above the Stock chart.. so both can use the navigator.

Comment: See the example http://jsfiddle.net/X8Crp/8/ which enalbe navigator from highstock, hope that its your goal

Comment: @SebastianBochan, that is perfect - except that I need to show 2-5 spline graphs below that bar graph.. both using the xAxis (time) as their common point. I've started working on one here: http://jsfiddle.net/revive/g4KLk/ but I don't understand how to configure the top column chart the same as you have in your example (horizontal bar).. can you provide some direction there?? Thanks!

Comment: In case when you have a handlers, you need to call setExtremes() on the any chart which will set range on the xAxis.

Comment: @SebastianBochan would you be willing to adjust the jsfiddle I created to help me understand what you are referring to??

Comment: I mean catch handlers event, and call this action: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes

Comment: UPDATED COMMENT: (someone decided to redirect the jsfiddle to some emoticon site, so I updated the link) @ZekeDroid, you can get to the full WIP by going here: jsfiddle.net/revive/g4KLk/ (you can also remove /show/light from the other URL and it will work as well)

Comment: @SebastianBochan, I might have been unclear in what I am trying to accomplish. I simply need to format the data from these 2 charts http://jsfiddle.net/revive/n4H8U/ and understand how to use the API to make this chart display the graphs in the same way as jsfiddle.net/revive/g4KLk/ http://jsfiddle.net/revive/n4H8U/ jsfiddle.net/revive/g4KLk/.. does that make sense? How would I do that?

Comment: I know what is you goal, and I point you that you need to use setExtremes to zoom your chart.

Comment: NVM, we got it sorted though it had nothing to do with setExtremes.. as the concern was not zooming.. it was getting the DATA to present itself the way we needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with another developer (who's more savvy when it comes to JS API's) we were able to sort out the chart settings we needed to accomplish this. You can see the completed graph here:

https://revivemarketing.makes.org/thimble/MzM2NzI0MjI0/wgv-uber-meta-data-graph